# Alternative (synonym) to „demokratisieren“ in the sense of „make accessible to common people“

Tags: verb, single-word-request, synonym

[Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/demokratisieren):

> ***demokratisieren***
>
> 3. etwas, was Privilegierten vorbehalten war, allgemein zugänglich, erreichbar machen; z.B. *das Reisen demokratisieren*

I am wondering whether there is any alternative verb to *demokratisieren* in the sense aforementioned?

Comment: *Der Öffentlichkeit zugänglich machen* or even *veröffentlichen*? I’m curious about less bulky alternatives.

Answer (score 6):

Depending on your use-case, *popularisieren* may be an alternative, but mind that it is not a synonym. It does not connotate that access was privileged beforehand, more that it has not been widely known. It also connotates that the subject is actually popular afterwards, rather than just accessible. This is usually used for cultural and consumable goods.

Then there is *publik machen*, which is sharing knowledge previously limited to a smaller body of people. This is actually a synonym, but only for knowledge (and I certainly wouldn't use *demokratisieren* in that context). Duden even allows *publikmachen*, though I haven't seen it written like that anywhere.

Comment: +1 for *popularisieren*. I find the meaning, which Duden states to *demokratisieren* off the mark, since only the *demos* (Greek: people) part is useful, and the *kratie* (Greek: power) not applicable.

Answer (score 4):

- *für den Massenmarkt verfügbar machen*,
  also *für alle …* ’everyone‘
  or *für jeden …* ’anyone‘ (synonymous *jedermann* is better avoided)
- *für die [breite] Masse anbieten*,
  also *für [Otto] Normalverbraucher …* ’Joe Sixpack‘,
  similar: *für den Kleinen Mann [auf der Straße] …*
  or *für die Kleinen Leute …*
- *auf dem Endverbrauchermarkt einführen*,
  also *… [fest] etablieren*
- *zu einem Massenprodukt machen*
- *massenfähig machen*
- *gesellschaftsfähig machen*
  (like *hoffähig* and *salonfähig*, this could be understood to apply to the noble class, *die bessere Gesellschaft*, e.g. a former taboo or stigmatized topic)
- *Volks-* as in *Volkswagen, Volksempfänger*
  (sometimes seen as a problematic word, but at least Bild still gets away with it)
- *[massenweise / allgemein] verbreiten*
- *durchsetzen*
- *den [Massen-]Markt durchdringen*,
  *… erreichen*,
  *… penetrieren*
  or *… erschließen*

Answer (score 0):

Maybe *legitimieren* in the sense of *befugen*.